# Getting ClassNotFoundException in maven project even though <addClasspath> is true

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

I have a maven project that I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException in. The exact error is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

In my pom.xml I have the correct dependencies listed and I have addClasspath set to true:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
  <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
       <archive>
         <manifest>
           <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
           <mainClass>SNIP</mainClass>
         </manifest>
       </archive>
       </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Indeed, everything was running fine before.  I was able to run the program using "java -jar app.jar"  Then something changed and I started to get the ClassNotFoundException.  The only thing I did was import my src directory into svn and check it out again.  I didn't make any changes to my pom file.  Any ideas why I was able to run the program fine before but now I'm getting the error?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you need to build uber jar

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  But I still can't figure out why it was working before.. hmm

Comment: while building jar maven dont add dependency. you need to specify them explicitly while running application.